# How to check where Apache is looking for a php.ini file?

Tags: apache, php

I have a feeling that Apache is using a different php.ini file that the one I am editing. I make a change in my php.ini file, restart Apache, and the change doesn't take affect. So I don't know what to do anymore.

Any ideas?

Update: Found out it's using the right php.ini file...but I still don't know what to do!

Comment: ***Note:*** The `php-cli`'s `php.ini` file is different then `apache2`'s `php.ini` file. I suggest symbolic linking one to another to keep them in sync and avoid confusion!

Comment: `$ php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini`

Comment: `echo php_ini_loaded_file();` [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php), `php ANYTHING` in console gives stuff for CLI php which in lot of if not most cases is a different one.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To find the file that's being run by PHP, create a phpinfo file (just `<?php phpinfo();?>`) and look for the 'Configuration File (php.ini) Path' directive.

Comment: mine shows 'no value', how to fix ?

Comment: This *only* works on Linux, what about Windows?

Answer (score 13):

from the command line, run

```
php -i |grep "php.ini"
```

This will describe the location php is loading its ini file from. You can reconfigure the php.ini location by recompiling php.

Comment: this will show you ini file of php-cli which is not necessarily the same one used by apache php module

Comment: To get the apache cli, I found `sudo find /etc/ -name php.ini | grep 'apache2'` got me what I needed.

Comment: Here is a command for Ubuntu `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*.load` , above comment will only work if you have only 1 version of PHP.

Answer (score 10):

The output from `phpinfo()` will contain this. When using PHP as an Apache module, it can be configured using `PHPIniDir` in `httpd.conf` (or similar).

Comment: `PHPIniDir` is the actual and correct solution to the problem of a missing php.ini file when running in Apache as a module.

Answer (score 4):

To get the php.ini file which is being used by Apache you will probably have to add `phpinfo()` into a .php file and open it in the browser. As `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini` will outout the same as `php --ini` would. Which php.ini is used for the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Question for you, what platform are you running on unix or windows? 
<strike>If it is unix based, check if your php.ini is residing in the same directory as /etc/httpd. Again, installation of apache can vary so check...or issue the command "find / -name php.ini -print" (without quotes) to see which one is it you are using</strike>

Ok. Since you said you have found the correct php.ini, sounds like something is missing when you edited the php.ini and reloaded apache. Look in the log directory /var/log/httpd for error_log and check to see if there was errors...that would be a start!

Comment: nothing called httpd in /var/log...maybe not a Snow Leopard place to look?

Comment: Hmmm...you are running Snow Leopard (I am not familiar with it but can guess it is similar to freebsd variant)...it would be worth your while to dig around in /var/log and see where the log file is kept...or even better check in the httpd.conf (the configuration file for apache) to see where the actual log file is stored into...