# PHP don't load extension

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I wrote my extension.

Ubuntu system.

```
php -c "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" -r "echo extension_loaded('my');"
 => 1 OK!
```

But under apache - nothing!

```
echo extension_loaded('my'); 
=> ""
```

Why?

Php ini shows:

"`Loaded Configuration File /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini"`

Comment: [Check](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) if your extension is loaded using `extension_loaded()`

Comment: I wrote.. but not loaded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724511/how-to-check-where-apache-is-looking-for-a-php-ini-file

Comment: Did you restart/reload Apache?  PHP in Apache caches the INI file in the module until Apache is reloaded.

Comment: Did you build the extension with your PHP version or got it from other sources?

Comment: I solved it, My server had two versions php.... command line builded from sources and apache another one!

Answer (score 1):

I always put my extensions in separate files and place them inside

`/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/`

suppose I wanted to load mongo php extension, i would perform the following steps:

`sudo pecl install mongo`

and once that is completed successfully, I would make a

`echo "extension=mongo.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mongo.ini`

after that I would reload or restart the server

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and I think the issue is what the extension path is relative to when running under apache.

The default setting

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

works in CLI because PHP is called directly.

When running under apache i got it to work when specified the absolute path with forward slashes:

```
extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"
```