# Facing this problem "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini."

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, size

Tried solving problem by editing php.ini file and changed 
upload_max_filesize "64M"
memory_limit "1200M"
max_execution_time 300.

problem stays the same. Any help?

Comment: Did you edit the right `php.ini`? Did you restart the web server?

Comment: You should also update `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: @Amadan i updated the one under /etc. hope that is the correct one..

Comment: you can run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in any of your webpage to see if you updated the right php.ini

Comment: @Wreigh may be you are right.. i might not be updating the right php.ini. phpinfo() returns the old value of all the parameters mentioned above. Any idea on what to do next?

Comment: Track down which `php.ini` is used by Apache - should be in `phpinfo()` output: [How to check where Apache is looking for a php.ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724511/how-to-check-where-apache-is-looking-for-a-php-ini-file)

Comment: It turns out that the php.ini file which i edited is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change both in php ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
max_execution_time = 300
```

and restart the server
if it is not working try adding following code into theme folder in functions.php:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

if it still does not work try adding following code into htaccess file in root directory:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

if still doesnot works try contacting to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Update below values from php.ini and restart apache server.

```
post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M 
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000  
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to paste this code in wp-config.php

`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`

For more info visit this link: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/fix-wordpress-memory-exhausted-error-increase-php-memory/